# Django objects in array shows as its id's

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I have an **UserProfile**, which have *OneToOneField* **User**.

In **UserProfile** I have *ManyToManyField* **Orders**.

When I get the orders from user.profile, it returns the array of it ID's, not the entire objects.

**UserProfile:**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='userprofile', on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=False)
    orders = models.ManyToManyField(Order, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**Order:**

```
class Order(models.Model):
    car_brand = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    car_model = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    repair_type = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Serializers:**

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['car_brand', 'car_model', 'repair_type', 'user']


class UserProfileSerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    orders = OrderSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['user', 'orders']

class UserSerializer(RegisterSerializer):

    def save(self, request):
        user = super().save(request)
        user.username = self.data.get('username')
        user.email = self.data.get('email')
        user.password = self.data.get('password')
        orders = []
        profile = UserProfile(user, orders)
        profile.user_id = user.id
        profile.id = user.id
        profile.save()
        return user
```

And, the main part, if I making a GET request with Postman, I get this:

```
{
    "user": 5,
    "orders": [
        {
            "car_brand": "Ford",
            "car_model": "Galaxy",
            "repair_type": "Gearbox",
            "user": 5
        }
    ]
}
```

And yeah, that's exactly what I want.
But React GET returns another:

[image]

11 in this case, it is a ID of order, which described above.

So, the main question: How to save this order not as ID, or read it not as ID.

**UPD**

My React GET Request:

```
 fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users/dj-rest-auth/user/', {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    Authorization: `Token ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`

                }
            })
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => {
                    console.log(data)
                    setUser(data)
                    setId(data.pk)
                });
```

My React PUT Request:

```
let tmp = {
                "user": id,
                "orders": user.profile.orders
            }
            console.log(JSON.stringify(tmp))


            fetch(`http://localhost:8000/profiles/${id}/`, {
                method: 'PUT',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    Authorization: `Token ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(tmp)
            })
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => {
                    console.log(data)
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        window.location.replace('http://localhost:3000/profile');
                    }, 60000);

                });
```

Comment: Please see how to make a [mre]. Your question suggests everything is fine with the code you show as it gives you the expected result from postman. You don't share any of your react code which is where you have the problem.

Comment: What is the `RegisterSerializer` derived by the `UserSerializer`?

Comment: @DavidLu, ‘from dj_rest_auth.registration.serializers import RegisterSerializer’